# Mongoose - Search dates stored as strings by date range

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongo db with a paymentDate field stored as strings YYYY-MM-DD (I can't change how these are unfortunately), and I need to do a date range search on them.

I found a post suggesting something like this:

```
coll.find({paymentDate: new RegExp("^(2016-02-18|2016-06-19)", "i")});
```

But I can't seem to get that to work at all.

Any help is appreciated, I've hit a dead end here.

Comment: Are dates you want to use as min and max constant?

Comment: The date range will change and is provided as parameters. This is just for testing purposes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Storing dates as strings in YYYY-MM-DD format works fine in this case as the string ordering matches the date ordering so you can do:

```
coll.find({paymentDate: {$gte: "2016-02-18", $lte: "2016-06-19"}});
```

Comment: having a proof would be much better, anyway you get my +1, consider adding some working samples please

Answer (score 0):

Your first objective should be changing the schema and use `Date` instead of `String`. But if it's really not possible and you can't think of a really complicated `RegEx`, you can do it with `Javascript` using [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/), but it's performance will be much slower:

```
db.test.find({
    $where: function () {
        var docDate = new Date(this.paymentDate);
        return (docDate >= new Date('2016-02-18') && docDate <= new Date('2016-02-19'))
    }
})
```